# Google sheets: MAX Null Value

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, max

I have a formula working pretty well that will lookup a value into a range of data and then retrieve the max value from a different range (it's student test scores that they submit through a GoogleForm, I'm searching for their email addresses and only want to pull their top score through to a dashboard (they can sit the test multiple times)).

This all works well but I'm stuck on the last bit. Instead of the max value of students who haven't taken the test yet (and therefore not having an email address in the lookup range) appearing as 0, I'd like it to be blank (or anything else). This is because I need to be able to see which students have taken the test, have an email address in the responses sheet to be looked up and scored 0 (!) and those who haven't taken the test at all - at the moment there is no differentiation.

I've tried all different combos of IF like I normally would but can't crack this!

=ArrayFormula(max(if('Problem Solving 1'!$B:$B=$A2,'Problem Solving 1'!$C:$C)))

[Here's the formula I have that works perfectly apart from the last bit!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm2zE.png)

@whatapalaver

Thanks, but your answer still gives 0 for no entry, not nothing or -99.. Here are some further screen shots to try and clarify my working.

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7QeA.png)

[Responses Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwh39.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! At StackOverflow, we are helping developers to get stronger. However, we won't never let company get rid of them by requesting free jobs on this forum. So in order to distinct yourself from these sharks, show us some effort, pieces of code, some bugs, or other... And then we will help you! Please take the tour and read "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" [help/dont-ask], "What topics can I ask about here?" [help/on-topic] and [mcve]!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite tricky to help without seeing some examples of your layout, so I've had to guess what you have going on in Cols A, B C for example.

This formula might give you some clues as to how you could deal with it. It's an array formula as yours was. It returns a large -ve number (you can pick what is appropriate) to reflect an absent test result.

In response to you further comments, I've amended the formula. So in the example I have mocked up in google sheets, it looks like this:

`=ArrayFormula(max(if($A:$A=$E5,$B:$B,-99)))`

[image]

Your formula would probably need to be:

`=ArrayFormula(max(if('Problem Solving 1'!$B:$B=$A2,'Problem Solving 1'!$C:$C,-99)))`

The format of the IF is conditional statement, value if true, value if false (optional).

** Converting the -99 to text
This is starting to get a bit ugly which makes me think there must be a better way to deal with it, but you could wrap your entire ArrayFormula in an If statement. So IF(arrayFormula < 0 , "Not submitted" , ArrayFormula)

`=if(ArrayFormula(max(if('Problem Solving 1'!$B:$B=$A2,'Problem Solving 1'!$C:$C,-99))) <0, "Not submitted", ArrayFormula(max(if('Problem Solving 1'!$B:$B=$A2,'Problem Solving 1'!$C:$C,-99))))`

Comment: Hi, not really sure how to reply to my own post, so have edited the original message!

Comment: I've amended my answer to help.

Comment: Why not use `FILTER` and drop the `ARRAYFORMULA` bit? `=IFERROR(MAX(FILTER(...), "")`

Comment: @tehhowch could you elaborate on that into my situation? Thanks

Comment: @whatapalaver that works almost perfectly thanks! I just don't want the blank to be -99! I seem to be able to change it to any number but it wont let me substitute in text, such as "-" or even nothing " ". Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @whatapalaver excellent work, works perfectly and with logic I understand! Interestingly, in the meantime we had used conditional formatting to substitute the -99 for a space. Thanks!

Comment: @whatapalaver hello, thanks so much for your help a while back. Now I am looking to replicate this in exactly the same way but extracting the LOWEST value from a list (with the same validation etc.). I thought it'd be as easy as swapping MAX for MIN but no :(